# How to change configuration of existing docker network

Tags: docker, networking

I have an existing (MacVLAN) docker network called "VPN" to which I normally attach docker containers that I all want to run on a VPN. There are two single 'host' docker containers running openvpn, each with their own IP, and I attach other containers to these as I please.

I have recently moved, and my new router is at address `192.168.0.1`. However, the old house's router had the gateway at `192.168.2.254`, and the existing docker network had the subnet mask, the IP range and the gateway all configured for this.

If I run `docker network inspect VPN` it gives:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "VPN",
        "Id": [anidea],
        "Created": [sometimenottolongago],
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "macvlan",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.2.0/24",
                    "IPRange": "192.168.2.128/28",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.2.254"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "parent": "enp5s0"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

There were two machines on the network, and I cannot access them currently. Both machines are a container to which other containers are attached to.
I have tried:

- Recreating the docker containers with new IP addresses on the subnet of the new home network. This doesn't work as the docker network "VPN" allows only IP's on the old range.
- Access the docker containers/machines at their old IP. Then I get a timeout; possibly I need to design some IP routing or something? This is where my knowledge (if any) starts getting cloudy.

I think the best is to just update the docker network "VPN" to play nice with the new Gateway/router/home network; I would like to change the `IPAM["Config"]` parameters to update for the new gateway and subnet. However, I can't find online how to do this (the only things that come up is how to change the *default* settings for the *default* docker network).

Long story short:
**How do I change configuration/parameters of an *existing* docker network?**

If, in the end, this is a bad way of doing things (for instance, if I can access the containers on the network as-currently-is), I'm also open for ideas.

The host machine is running ubuntu-server `20.04.1` LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simpler approach would be to delete the existing VPN network and create it anew with the new parameters and the same name.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to delete the network, because I cannot exactly remember how I made it originally - I lost the notes I made on how to make one. I will try to find it out again, but in the meantime - is it really not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach to this would be to delete the VPN network and create it anew with new parameters but the same name. If you use `docker-compose up` to recreate containers, include the `networks` section in the first container that you recreate.

First, run this to delete the existing network:

```
docker network rm VPN
```

Then add the macvlan network definition to `yml` of your first re-created container. Here is the `networks` section I used, adapted somewhat to your situation:

```
networks:
  VPN:
    driver: macvlan
    enable_ipv6: true                   # if needed
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.0.1
          ip_range: 192.168.0.8/30      # reserve some IP addresses for other machines
                                        # in that subnet - adjust as needed
        - subnet: xx:xx:xx:xx::/63      # put your IPv6 subnet here if needed
          gateway: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx::xx   # IPv6 (external) of your router
```

Alternatively, you could change your new router config to match the old one, and leave your macvlan VPN as is.

Comment: This worked; I also learned that you can create networks in a .yml or docker-compose file instead of having to create the network separately. Thank you!